# How to add image to quiz results based on results

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to display an image based on my character quiz result but I am having issues with the logic behind it. Here a snippet of the code on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Daryl13/p047yx91/

```
if (result === Warlock) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("result-image").src = 'warlock1.jpg';
    } else if (result === Titan) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("result-image").src = 'Titan1.jpg';
    } else if (result === Hunter) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("result-image").src = 'hunter.jpg';
    }
```

Tried this way but with no luck. This issue is getting the result and the images to corelate and display at the same time depending on the result. Seems like a simple solution but I am having no luck, any help would be appreciated. Would also like to log the result to local storage as a bonus tip would be great.

Comment: GetElementByClassName returns a collection, not a single element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelector` - it will find the first matching element. You were using `getElementsByClassName` which returns an HTML collection, rather than a single element. Also, you needed to wrap your string comparisons with quotes. Finally, you were using `result` to compare, but `result` is actually a long string, not a single word. Based on your jsfiddle, you may have multiple outcomes so the best way to handle it is to loop through and add the image as you go.

```
document.querySelector(".resultImage").innerHTML=''; // clear it out
myTypes.forEach(t => {
  let src=''
  if (t === "Warlock")  src = 'warlock1.jpg';
  else if (t === "Titan") src = 'Titan1.jpg';
  else if (t === "Hunter") src = 'hunter.jpg';
  if (src) document.querySelector(".resultImage").innerHTML += `<img src="${src}" />`
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kinglish/0f86jauc/4/

Comment: Awesome! Had to change the file path for the src to <img src="assets/images/${t}1.jpg" /> . Seems to be working fine, thanks!

Comment: @DarylHowai - sorry I had a typo in my code. I changed this line: `if (src) document.querySelector(".resultImage").innerHTML += <img src="${src}" />` - except I couldn't use backticks twice here, so copy it from the actual answer.